# vis.js fixed length edges

Tags: visualization, vis.js

Is it possible to give an edge a fixed length? Even if I set the length of individual edges, physic engine changes it.

I am trying to visualize 3 clusters, each with couple hundred of nodes. There is an option to aggregate the cluster into couple of nodes. I want to connect these aggregated nodes with really short edges and give these nodes high mass so they will repulse other clusters like they were doing when they had hundreds of nodes.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the answer to this question these days is YES! The [network/edges visjs.org docs](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/edges.html) describe a "length" option:

> "The physics simulation gives edges a spring length. This value can
>   override the length of the spring in rest."

So when you're setting up your edges you might do something like this to make an extra long edge:

```
myEdges.push({from:'nodeid1', to:'nodeid2', length:300});
```

The length by default is about 95 I think, so a length of 300 would be about three times the normal.

If you want to change the default edge length (not including any which you've set explicitly on edges) then this is the 'springLength' of the network, so pass an option while making the network:

```
var network = new vis.Network(container, data,
  {"physics": {"barnesHut": {"springLength":100, "springConstant": 0.04}}}
);
```

The physics engine might constrain things and sort of hide the changes you're trying to see, so you may also need to tweak things like 'springConstant'.

Comment: This does not work for edges from and to the same node. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set a fixed length. You can play around though with the default `springLength` and `springConstant` though, checkout the docs on physics:

http://visjs.org/docs/network/physics.html

Comment: Do you think that it's possible if I dig around the code so the physics engine will not change the length of the edge?